# Multibinding for attached property

Tags: wpf

In `WPF` you can use `MultiBinding` for normal properties. E.g.:

```
<TextBlock>
   <TextBlock.Text>
      <MultiBinding>
         ...
      </MultiBinding>
   </TextBlock.Text>
</TextBlock>
```

**How would you do this for an attached property** like `Canvas.Left`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can directly do that inline like this:

```
<TextBlock>
  <Canvas.Left>
     <MultiBinding>
        <Binding Path="ABC"/>
        <Binding Path="DEF"/>
      </MultiBinding>
  </Canvas.Left>
</TextBlock>
```

Comment: Lol. That never occurred to me :)

Comment: Yeah happens sometimes.. :)